# Is it possible to match "none" in XSL?

Tags: xslt

Given the following XML fragment:

```
<foo>
  <bar>1</bar>
  <bar>2</bar>
  <bar>3</bar>
</foo>
```

The following XSL should work:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates
    mode="items"
    select="bar" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="items" match="bar">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

**Is there a way I can use a similar format to this to apply a template when there are *no* `<bar/>` entities?** For example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates
    mode="items"
    select="bar" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="items" match="bar">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="items" match="none()">
  There are no items.
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for exlanation and a complete, short solution that uses only templates and no explicit conditional XSLT instructions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could also use this pattern to avoid extra chooses:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bar" mode="items"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="(.)[not(bar)]" mode="show-absence-message"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar" mode="items">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*" mode="show-absence-message">
    There are no items.
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 6):

## **Yes.**

But the logic should be:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo[not(bar)]">
   There are no items. 
</xsl:template>
```

**Note:** It's `foo` element which is having or not having `bar` children.

Comment: Upvoted, but I've gone with @Flack's answer as sometime's it's not possible to use the parent context.

Comment: @digitala: No problem. But **always it's possible to use this pattern matching**. @Flack's answer use a **push style** (`xsl:apply-tempates/@select`) and modes (`xsl:apply-tempates/@mode`) instead of this **pull style**.

Comment: @Alejandro. I agree, your solution has a better design, I just provided a valid alternative (mostly because you were faster :)), which can be sometimes convinient.

Comment: @Flack: Sorry for the notification, ja! I was just telling to the OP that the real difference is between push and pull style.

Answer (score 1):

No, when you have `apply-templates select="bar"` and the context node does not have any `bar` child elements then no nodes are processed and therefore no templates are applied. You could however change your code in the template doing the apply-templates to e.g.

```
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="bar">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>There are not items.</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Given the following XML fragment:

```
<foo>
    <bar>1</bar>
    <bar>2</bar>
    <bar>3</bar>
</foo>
```

> The following XSL should work:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="items" select="bar" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="items" match="bar">
 <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

**No, the `<xsl:apply-templates>` above doesn't select any node at all**.

> Is there a way I can use a similar
>   format to this to apply a template
>   when there are no  entities?

**Yes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*[not(bar)]">
      No <bar/> s.
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*[bar]">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(bar)"/> <bar/> s.
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<foo>
    <bar>1</bar>
    <bar>2</bar>
    <bar>3</bar>
</foo>
```

**the result is**:

```
3<bar/> s.
```

**When applied to this XML document**:

```
<foo>
    <baz>1</baz>
    <baz>2</baz>
    <baz>3</baz>
</foo>
```

**the result is**:

```
  No <bar/> s.
```